# Beautiful Soup not pulling all the html of a webpage

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to practice using `BeautifulSoup`. I am trying to pull the image address of football player images from this website: https://www.transfermarkt.com/jordon-ibe/profil/spieler/195652

When I '`inspect`' the code, the section that has the `img` `src` is below:

```
    <div class="dataBild">
    <img src="https://tmssl.akamaized.net//images/portrait/header/195652-1456301478.jpg?lm=1456301501" title="Jordon Ibe" alt="Jordon Ibe" class="">
<div class="bildquelle"><span title="imago">imago</span></div>            
</div>
```

So I was thinking that I could just use `BeautifulSoup` to find the `div` with `class = "DataBild"` as this is unique.

```
# Import the Libraries that I need
import urllib3
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the URL
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/jordon-ibe/profil/spieler/195652'
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
response = http.request('GET', url)


#Parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

player_img = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'dataBild'})
print (player_img)
```

This runs but it doesn't output anything. So I checked by just running `print(soup)`

```
# Import the Libraries that I need
import urllib3
import certifi
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Specify the URL
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/jordon-ibe/profil/spieler/195652'
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
response = http.request('GET', url)


#Parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable 'soup'
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.data, "html.parser")

print(soup)
```

This outputs

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr/><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

So it is obviously not pulling all the HTML from the webpage?
Why is this happening? And is my logic of looking for `div class = DataBild sound`?

Answer (score 2):

The site seems to inspect whether the `User-Agent` header of the request is valid.

So you need to add the header like this:

```
import urllib3
import certifi

url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.com/jordon-ibe/profil/spieler/195652'
http = urllib3.PoolManager(cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED', ca_certs=certifi.where())
response = http.request('GET', url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
print(response.status)
```

This prints `200`. If you remove the headers, you get `404`.

Any non-empty `User-Agent` value (after trimming whitespace) seems to work.